# SSL Certificate only works within Local Network

Tags: windows, http, ssl, https

I am running windows server 2003 standard and have installed the ssl cert as per Godaddy's instructions. Let me know what information you need from me. Attempting to access the website securely outside of our network the page does not load. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use the same domain name internally and externally? Does it match the CN of the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Although it would help if you provided more information (like what error the clients are getting), I’m going to guess that you are missing the intermediate certificates that GoDaddy uses. These need to be installed on the server where the SSL certificate is installed.

Follow the [procedure here](http://help.godaddy.com/article/4875).

Comment: Whenever clients browse to the site; it does not load the page and whenever I check the intermediate certificates, the GoDaddy certificate is there.